# Unprotect and change style with vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheet1.Unprotect
Sheet1.Cells(13, "E").Locked = False
Sheet1.Range("E13").Style.Name = "Normal"
Sheet1.Protect
```

Produces:

> The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet.
>   To make changes, click on Unprotect Sheet in the Review tab (...)

On the other hand:

```
Sheet1.Unprotect
Sheet1.Cells(13, "E").Locked = False
Sheet1.Protect
```

runs instead properly.

Comment: dont you have a password? `Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="Your Password"`

Comment: Good idea but no, I did not set the password. Btw, `Sheet1.Unprotect
Sheet1.Cells(13, "E").Locked = False
Sheet1.Protect` runs smoothly

Comment: I just tried your code, it worked fine for me. But I made a mistake with that. maybe you are doing the same thing. While while giving the sheet name as `Sheet1` does not mean `Sheets("Sheet 1")`. `Sheet1` means the first sheet in the workbook. Pay attention to that. :)

Comment: Why set Locked to false when the sheet is already unprotected? When you reprotect the sheet (assuming no error) then that cell will be unprotected... unless of course that's your desired behavior.

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the `Sheet1.Protect`, run the macro and exit at the error, then try to set the Style manually?

Comment: I see odd behaviour: `Sheet1.Range("E13").Style.Name = "Percent"` results in `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` (on an unprotected sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with the, 'The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make changes, click on Unprotect Sheet in the Review tab (...)', error message coming up.

Realized I had protection on an another worksheet in the workbook which had to be turned off before I could modify the Normal style. Makes sense if you think about it!

Once all protection was turned off I can modify the Normal Style.

Rogerc